# can singleton class in java act as a cache mechanism?

Tags: java, design-patterns, caching, singleton

My java applciation is a console application.I am reading a lot of read only data and keeping it under a List called  flatFileList.

```
 List flatFileList = readLotofDataFromFile(fileName);
```

Now this flatFileList is used in almost all parts of the code. I do not want to read the datafile again. So I created a singleton class , and a getInstance()

I use this getInstance() method anywhere I need to get the flatFileList object.My question is this,can this singleton pattern be called as a cache mechanism ? because I am not re reading the data again from the flatfile.

Comment: I did the same mechanism special for small database tables and configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that's exactly what a cache is for: parts of (or all) data is read into a usually non-persistent memory close to the process that requires the data to improve access speed.

Answer (score 3):

Other possible solution is to use [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) which also may be used as a cache mechanism.